# Want to share post in LinkedIn with post specific og:image

Tags: angular, share, linkedin-api, meta-tags

I have angular 4 web application. Where I need to share some post to linked in with URL containing thumbnail preview.

**What I did is:**
Am using the static meta infromation for index.html page & while navigating to another page, i am updating meta information. from that page i am sharing post to linkedin. Successfully able to share the url with og:image but the thumbnail preview contains og:image from main index.html.

**Below is index.html meta information:**

```
<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="Title Example">
<meta property="og:type" content="Article">
<meta name="image" property="og:image" content="[Image URL here]">
<meta name="description" property="og:description" content="Description Example">
<meta name="author" content="Example">
```

**Below is code is to update meta information for Share.html**

```
this.meta.updateTag({ prefix: 'og: http://ogp.me/ns#' , name: 'title', content: 'Title Example Badge'});
this.meta.addTag({ prefix: 'og: http://ogp.me/ns#' , name: 'description', content: 'Badge Description '});
this.meta.updateTag({ prefix: 'og: http://ogp.me/ns#' , property: 'og:image', content: this.imageURL, itemprop: 'image' });
this.meta.updateTag({ prefix: 'og: http://ogp.me/ns#' , property: 'og:image:type', content: 'image/png' });
this.meta.updateTag({ prefix: 'og: http://ogp.me/ns#' , property: 'og:url', content: this.routerUrl , itemprop: 'url' });
```

**What I want is:**
I want to share the URL with updated meta information & og:image.

Comment: Are you doing any server-side rendering? If not, LinkedIn is probably only ever loading the index file, it won't load Angular and render your app.

Comment: I am using SSR but still not capturing the data by LinkedIn, any idea to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Your angular project has an `index.html` file like so...

```
<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="Title Example">
```

You will only be able have a custom share url title/image/description, etc., if you are dynamically rendering that data here, in your index.html file.  So, for instance, if your URL is...

```
example.com?post=123456
```

Then you would want something like....

```
<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="Post #<?php print($post[id]); ?>">
```

To get a resultant index.html page like...

```
<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="Post #123456">
```

In that case, you will need to handle...

- 1 - Rendering the data with server-side processing.
- 2 - Appending `?entryid=...` data to the URLs you are sharing through LinkedIn.